# Python multiprocess non-blocking intercommunication using Pipes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

Is it possible to receive process intercommunications using Pipes in a non-blocking fashion?

Consider the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

def f(conn):
    time.sleep(3)
    conn.send('Done')
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    while True:
       print('Test')
       msg = parent_conn.recv()
       if msg == 'Done':
          break
    print('The End')
    p.join()
```

The `parent_conn.recv()` will block the while-loop until a message is received. Is there a way to listen for messages in a non-blocking way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the poll function.  Change your while loop like this:

```
 while True:
       print('Test')
       if parent_conn.poll():
           msg = parent_conn.recv()
           if msg == 'Done':
              break
       else:
           do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [`multiprocessing.Pipe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Pipe) and [`multiprocessing.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pipe#multiprocessing.Connection) docs, a `Connection` has the `poll()` method for that.